# Installing .NET Framework 2.0 SDK on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, .net-framework, .net-2.0

I'm installing some older packages with npm to support an existing project, and at one point while trying to install node-sass, it looks for the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK. I've tried downloading the installer from [the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/download/dotnet-2.0-SDK) and [download.cnet.com](https://download.cnet.com/NET-Framework-2-0-Software-Development-Kit-SDK-x64/3000-2206_4-10728200.html) but when I run them, the mouse cursor flickers but nothing else happens. No installation window comes up. The installers from the two sites are binary identical. I've tried this on both my own machine and a colleague's machine with the same lack of results.

How can I install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK on a Windows 10 machine?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot install just .NET Framework V2 on Windows 10.  .NET Framework V3.5 includes .NET2 .

Look in Windows 10 Programs and Features, Windows Features and you will see (a) The .NET Features you can install and (b) that .NET 3.5 includes V2.

This link:

[.NET V2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=6041)

Has V2 download but it only supports XP and Server 2003.

.NET2 SDK follows the same rules so as to keep packages in line for various operating systems.

Note: You may be able to set up an XP Virtual Machine and develop / change the V2 package that way and then see if it will run on a V3.5 (and greater) machine. That may possibly work for you.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried downloading various .NET 3.5 packages on my and my colleague's machine and I get the same symptom. The files appear to do nothing at all when executed.

Comment: The older package is an issue so try the XP machine approach, If you can make a working package that way, it might possibly run in a modern machine. Otherwise you need to upgrade the older package.

Comment: The thing is, I've already got .NET 2.0, 3.5, etc. on my Windows machine and I can just run npm without mucking about with VMs. Surely it must be possible to do the same on another Windows 10 machine!

Comment: I do not know how you can do that.  Updating the package seems the only practical next step.

Comment: Can't update any npm packages because I have no assurances that it won't break anything. It probably won't, but I need to know that it definitely won't.

Comment: I don't know what to tel you. The trains have left the station never to return, leaving you in a pickle.